# what is this piece of javascript code doing? I am working on react context api where this piece of code has been used. Can anybody explain?

Tags: javascript

Can anybody explain to me what is happening here?

```js
const boundActions={};
for (const key in actions) {
  boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch)
}
```

Is it destructuring or something else? I am new to this so I have almost no idea. If it is not destructuring then what is it exactly called? It would be super helpful if anybody could explain.

Comment: There is no destructring here. Which part of the code do you suspect is destructuring? The `const boundActions: Actions` on the first line is actually TypeScript.

Comment: That's not javascript. That looks like Typescript. It means create a variable called `boundActions` of type `Actions`. In a language like C++ or Java it would look like: `const Actions boundActions`

Comment: no destructring here this line `const boundActions: Actions = {}` is creating const object
and inside for loop `boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch)` inserting key values or storing in that object that you define above
For Example: It will looks like 
`boundActions={name:'John'}`

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies. I actually have a similar code, so I misunderstood this to be javascript, so thank you for clarifying. I was suspecting that the third line of code was destructuring. I haven't seen this method of inserting key values in an object earlier. This was new to me and specially that (dispatch)  after actions[key] made it even more confusing. cant we just write actions[key]??

Comment: `actions[key]` returns a function `actions[key](dispatch)` *executes* the function.

Comment: could you provide reference to code examples similar to this?